# how to set mysql server time zone

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Helo. Im running a Spring Boot application which would throw the error

> The server time zone value 'Hora estándar oeste, Sudaméri' is
>   unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure
>   either the server or JDBC driver

This error is thrown when i try to run the application. After some googling i updated the MySQL dialect to # 8 and the Hibernate dependency on Maven with no success. Maybe you experts can help me.

My application.properties:

```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_worker
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=Anderson1
    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
    spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=Select 1
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

My pom.xml

I used MySQL Workbench to create the server and already tried to change the default-time-zone to UTC-04:00 which is my timezone in MySQL Workbench but that didnt work either. Some help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps try `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_worker?serverTimezone=America/New_York`

Comment: that solved the problem. Thanks a lot